# How to send a variable data from server (python file) to an html file if I'm including it with Jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using Python and Flask to host a website.

Server side code:

'''

```
@app.route('\')
def home_page():
     return render_template("index.html", year=current_year)
```

'''

Now in my index.html I have included the footer (this is there for all pages) with Jinja. That is,
`{% include "footer.html" %}`, but I don't know how to pass the year value to the footer.html file.

Answer (score 0):

In `footer.html`, add:

```py
<p> {{ year }} </P
```

This will pick the value of year from the `homepage()` view function.